# Getting started with Django - base.py - ImportError: No module named blog

Tags: python, django

I am working through "getting started with django", the video series. 
I have spend some time googling and reviewing answers here and there.

I am only on the first lesson and I am seeing some issues with importing a module named "blog" when I:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It seems to me that the version of Django I have is more recent (but still, a stable version). For the base.py file, I had found it on github and loaded it. I reviewed and it was the same as specified in the tutorial.

Here is the file that I am using:

```
(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/microblog$ cat microblog/settings/base.py
import os

import dj_database_url

here = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)
PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")
root = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x)

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

ADMINS = (
    ("Supreme Master", "user@email.com"),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = root("..", "uploads")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = root("..", "static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root("..", "assets"),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'CREATE-YOUR-OWN-SECRET-CODE'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'microblog.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'microblog.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    root("templates"),
)

DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'blog',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

If we look at the value for "LOCAL_APPS", blog is there but I'm not really sure what should happen here next or how I can remedy this situation to get through the tutorial and learn how / why this works as it does.

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Have you actually created the blog app?

Comment: I have not beyond just trying to run the initial app using this config file. Of course, I have tried removing "blog" from the config file but it still causes issues. Is there anything I can do as a stop gap to just make it work for learning purposes?

Comment: The tutorial should have showed you how to create the app. There is no reason to bypass anything or use a stop-gap; just follow the instructions. If that tutorial is not working for you, use the [standard Django one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

That look in your installed aps and created columns in database.